# INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK error with debug version code 1 inconsistent with 0

Tags: android, android-emulator, build.gradle

I have built an Android app on Android Studio version 2.3.3. As I try to deploy the app to a phone (lennovo) or an emulator (GenyMotion) I get an error, which says:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl235652946.tmp/4_yCommerceApp-b_c-dev-debug version code 1 inconsistent with 0.
```

I have looked at various posts here and tried the approaches below, none of which seems to help

1. Did a clean build followed by a rebuild after a restart of the Android Studio
2. Disconnected and reconnected devices
3. I deleted the `.idea`, `.gradle` and build directories and built again

Any suggestions to solve this pls? What is the version code being referred to here? I see one version code in the AndroidManifest.xml like below:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
```

I don't see any other version code anywhere else. BTW, I did not use an Android emulator as they seem to take hours to start. My processor is AMD and not Intel. I have the ARM images downloaded for the emulators.

Comment: Is your applicationId same in Manifest and gradle?

Comment: @Ayush, Sorry, What should I check for.

Comment: You should check if your application package name is correct

Comment: @Ayush, I could not find anything wrong in the gradle and the manifest files. My deployments to the emulator and phone is now working :-) I am not sure what change of mine made it work though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well @user132797 could you at least check your git for changes? because .. at least now it`s working .. is one invalid solution. I have the same issue and have to look elsewhere for an answer.

Comment: This may also be called “Existing base version code … inconsistent with …”.

Answer (score 17):

The trouble maybe caused by **Instant Run** feature of new Gradle.

Try disable Instant Run by going into ***File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run***

Answer (score 2):

Some strange circumstances might cause this. That works for me:

Menu "Build" > "Rebuild Project"

Then run app on device or emulator, and error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I have this once every so many build, I wait a few moments and then run it again. In 90% of the situations it works after that. Not really the best solution, but it does work (where the other solution didn't change anything).